# "hashCode" and "toString" should not be called on array instances (SonarLint)

Tags: java, arrays, sonarlint

I am passing my code through SonarLint and I came across this linter violation:
`"hashCode" and "toString" should not be called on array instances`.

This is my code:

```
byte[] lblobPic;
lblobPic = r.get(PEOPLE.PPIC);
if (lblobPic != null) {
    String argStr = lblobPic.toString();
    peopleDto.setUrlPic(argStr);
}
```

SonarLint gives the following code snippet as a hint to improve my code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )  {
    String argStr = Arrays.toString(args);
    int argHash = Arrays.hashCode(args);    
}
```

How should I change my code to satisfy the linter and why?

Comment: you couldn't ... what did you try? it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Why are you passing the `args` String array into methods that don't take parameters?

Comment: I think it is a good question that does not deserve the downvotes! In general: I think this question is independent of jooq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actual Answer**

SonarLint is suggesting to you, that instead of calling `toString()` on the array instance, you should rather use the `Arrays` utility's method.

It suggests you to change your code to something along the lines:

```
byte[] lblobPic;
lblobPic = r.get(ALUNO.PFOTO);
if (lblobPic != null) {
    String argStr = Arrays.toString(lblobPic);
    peopleDto.setUrlPic(argStr);
}
```

**Reason behind Answer**

**a) Readability for Humans**

Consider the following code snippet:

```
String[] strings = { "foo", "bar", "bla", "boo" };

System.out.println(strings.toString());
// prints: [Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922 

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
// prints: [foo, bar, bla, boo]
```

The Linter rule assumes, that a developer actually wants a readable output of an array (considering its elements) and suggests you to use `Arrays.toString()` method which does this (as outlined in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]))).

Similarly, `Arrays.hashCode()` considers the elements of the given array in hashing (as outlined in [the docoumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(boolean[]))).

**b) Determinism**
(per @andi-turner's suggestion)

The `Arrays` utility's methods, take only the elements into account when constructing a string / calculating a hash. You will always end up with the same string/hash, when using an input array consisting of the same strings (or values of another type) in the same sequence. `yourArray.toHashcode()` or `yourArray.toString()` does not give you that.

Comment: Seeing as it is a `byte` array, it is possible they actually need a variation of `new String(lblobPic)`. Don't know OPs exact use-case, though.

Comment: I think the other thing that is worth pointing out explicitly is that `String[] strings2 = { /* the same elements */ };` will have a different `toString()` and `hashCode()`: `7852e922` is not something calculated from the elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
String argStr = lblobPic.toString();
```

should better be

```
String argStr = Arrays.toString(lblobPic);
```

as the original Object.toString would give a cryptic hex address.

However what you want to achieve, storing bytes as String is a no-go in java,
as java uses Unicode for String and char (two bytes, UTF-16), always with a conversion (of an assumed text encoding of those bytes).

Sometimes such bytes are Base64 encoded:

```
byte[] lblobPic = r.get(ALUNO.PFOTO);
if (lblobPic != null) {
    String argStr = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encode(lblobPic);
    peopleDto.setUrlPic(argStr);
}
```

Better still to provide a `byte[]` field in the DTO.

---

*Should the further processing be a problem; there exist embedding of images.*

How (normal) Base64 can be used for HTML with an embedded image:

```
    String argStr = Base64.getEncoder().encode(lblobPic);
    String html = "<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + argStr + "\" alt=\"\">";
```

(JPEG assumed here.)